# SharePoint 2013 Web site asking for authentication in all Mobile Phones

Tags: sharepoint-server, anonymous-authentication, mobile

We have an Internet Facing SP 2013 web application for which Anonymous Authentication is enabled. Funny thing we are encountering is that on trying to access this site from Mobile, we are getting Username Password prompt, however on clicking Cancel the site opens up with all the contents. I have gone through all the various forums and tried the following steps :

1. Edited the compat.browser file and changed capability name="isMobileDevice"  to false
2. Tried making changes in the web.config file of the web app file and tried adding the following browserCaps tag and adding Filter for isMobileDevice=false
3. The MobileBrowserView feature is deactivated on activating it I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error. So deactivated the feature again.

Also I'm not able to recreate this issue on my desktop If I add ?Mobile=1 to my url. On doing this I'm not getting a credential prompt. So I'm not able to trace the issue in Fiddler as well as a result of this. Also this same set-up is running fine on a lower environment and I'm not getting the credential prompt, however this issue is occuring in the PROD environment.

Please suggest if anyone has encountered this before and the fix for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Device Channels](https://academy.bindtuning.com/deactivate-sharepoint-2013-mobile-view/), which lets you override the default (and failing) mobile view. Device Channels target different group of devecies. It's not a simple setting, but it let's you have control of what you display to anonymous mobile users.

SharePoint reads the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` attribute to determine which device channel to use. Desktop uses the default and blank input of Device Inclusion Rules. Mobile devices is easy to target with the fallback of `$FALLBACKMOBILEUSERAGENTS;`. IPad is also ease to target, just use `iPad` as value of  Device Incusion Rules. But Android Tablet is tough. If you type Android, you target all Android devices; tablets and phones since the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` of Android is similar to each other.  [Android phones uses `Mobile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5344382/286244) in its `HTTP_USER_AGENT` which you need to add before `Android` targeting tablets. Otherwise you'll get the tablet device channel on Android phones as well.

When you test, you just add ?DeviceChannel=alias to see different views upon development. Be sure to test on real devices before deployment though.

```
http://sitecollection/site/pages/default.aspx
http://sitecollection/site/pages/default.aspx?DeviceChannel=ipad
http://sitecollection/site/pages/default.aspx?DeviceChannel=android
http://sitecollection/site/pages/default.aspx?DeviceChannel=mobile
```

[image]